# convert python string to json with formatting

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have following code that generates parent child relationship in list of lists

```
Levels=[['L1','L1','L2'],
        ['L1','L1','L3'],
        ['L1','L2'],
        ['L2','L2','L3'],
        ['L2','L2','L1'],
        ['L3','L2'],
        ['L4','L2','L1'],
        ['L4','L2','L4']]

def append_path(root, paths):
    if paths:
        child = root.setdefault(paths[0], {})
        append_path(child, paths[1:])

for p in Levels:
    append_path(root, p)

# Print results
import json
print(json.dumps(root,  indent=4))
```

The output generated is in the following format

```
{
    "L1": {
        "L1": {
            "L2": {},
            "L3": {}
        },
        "L2": {}
    },
    "L2": {
        "L2": {
            "L3": {},
            "L1": {}
        }
    },
    "L3": {
        "L2": {}
    },
    "L4": {
        "L2": {
            "L1": {},
            "L4": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert this into the following format which is required for my jquery visualization.

```
      "name": "L1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "L1",
           "children":[
              {
                "name":"L3",
                "children":[{}]
              },
              {
                "name":"L1",
                "children":[{}]
              }]
        },
        {
            "name":"L2",
            "children":[{}]
        }

      ]
```

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this recursively (after you've built `root` in the format you posted in your question):

```
def convert(d):
    return [{'name': k, 'children': convert(v) if v else [{}]} for k, v in d.items()]

print(json.dumps(convert(root),  indent=2))
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L3"
          },
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L1"
          }
        ],
        "name": "L2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "L2"
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {}
        ],
        "name": "L2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "L3"
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L4"
          },
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L1"
          }
        ],
        "name": "L2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "L4"
  },
  {
    "children": [
      {
        "children": [
          {}
        ],
        "name": "L2"
      },
      {
        "children": [
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L2"
          },
          {
            "children": [
              {}
            ],
            "name": "L3"
          }
        ],
        "name": "L1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "L1"
  }
]
```

Comment: This returns `[]` instead of `[{}]` when `d` is empty. The simple fix is to just replace `convert(v)` with `convert(v) if len(v) != 0 else [{}]`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Good catch. Thank you

Comment: @slider Thank you for the response I had a follow up question. can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331487/custom-json-formatting-in-python