# custom json formatting in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following code to generate json representation of list of lists.

```
Levels=[['L1','L1','L2'],
        ['L1','L1','L3'],
        ['L1','L2'],
        ['L2','L2','L3'],
        ['L2','L2','L1'],
        ['L3','L2'],
        ['L4','L2','L1'],
        ['L4','L2','L4']]

def append_path(root, paths):
    if paths:
        child = root.setdefault(paths[0], {})
        append_path(child, paths[1:])

for p in Levels:
    append_path(root, p)

def convert(d):
    return [{'name': k, 'children': convert(v) if v else [{}]} for k, v in d.items()]



# Print results
import json
print(json.dumps(convert(root),  indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
"name": "L1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "L1",
           "children":[
              {
                "name":"L3",
                "children":[{}]
              },
              {
                "name":"L1",
                "children":[{}]
              }]
        },
        {
            "name":"L2",
            "children":[{}]
        }

      ]
```

for the levels

```
Levels=[['L1','L1','L2'],
        ['L1','L1','L3'],
        ['L1','L2'],
```

I also need to encode the count of each level

for eg there is the path from `L1` which has two first level childrens `L1(2)` and `L2(1)` followed by `L2(1)` and `L3(1)` for next level .

```
L1(3)-->L1(2)-->L2(1)
             -->L3(1)
     -->L2(1)
```

How can I encode this count in my json output.

I want my final output to look like this

```
"name": "L1(3)",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "L1(2)",
           "children":[
```

Comment: You want to add values that can be extracted from the data already in a format that is neither intuitive nor machine readable in a simple way?

Comment: By "count", do you mean the number of leaf nodes or the height of a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root={}
Levels=[['L1','L1','L2'],
        ['L1','L1','L3'],
        ['L1','L2'],
        ['L2','L2','L3'],
        ['L2','L2','L1'],
        ['L3','L2'],
        ['L4','L2','L1'],
        ['L4','L2','L4']]

def append_path(root, paths):
    if paths:
        child = root.setdefault(paths[0], {})
        append_path(child, paths[1:])

for p in Levels:
    append_path(root, p)

def convert(d):
    templist=[]
    noofchildren=0
    if(len(d.items())==0):
        return ([{}],1)
    for k,v in d.items():
        temp,children=convert(v)
        noofchildren+=children
        if(temp):
            templist.append({"name":k+"("+str(children)+")",'children':temp})
        else:
            templist.append({'name': k+"("+str(children)+")", 'children':[{}]})

    return (templist,noofchildren)    

# Print results
import json
print(json.dumps(convert(root)[0],  indent=2))
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "name": "L1(3)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L1(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L2(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L3(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "L2(1)",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L2(2)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L3(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L1(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L3(1)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(1)",
        "children": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "L4(2)",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "L2(2)",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "L1(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "L4(1)",
            "children": [
              {}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```